# CakePHP 3.x Flash messages for ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

I have an application written in CakePHP 3.5.13

It makes use of the [Flash Component](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/flash.html) built into Cake. All of this is working when configured in the standard way, e.g.

```
// src/Controller/SomeController.php
public function foo()
{ 
    $this->Flash->set('Records updated', ['element' => 'success']);
    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}

// src/Template/SomeController/index.ctp
<?= $this->Flash->render() ?>
```

So if I access `/some-controller/foo` it will set the flash message, reload `index.ctp` and display it.

However, I want to modify things so that it's all done via ajax calls.

If I create a new template, `/src/Template/SomeController/index.ctp` and use the following jquery:

```
$('.foo-test').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/some-controller/foo'
    }).done(response) {
       //console.log(response);
       window.location.href = '/some-controller/index'; 
    });
});
```

When I click on an anchor with the class `.foo-test` it will make the ajax request.

But reloading the page (`window.location.reload`) doesn't display the flash message. Why is this, because that's equivalent to the browser reloading `/some-controller/index`, right?

The only way I can think to modify this is to have `foo()` return a JSON response. Where I've used `console.log(response)` I could then access the response data and determine the outcome, then add the flash message, e.g.

```
 if (response.success !== '') {
     $('#outcome').html(response.success).addClass('alert alert-success');
 }
```

Which would write the response message to a div with the ID `#outcome` and add the appropriate classes for styling purposes.

Surely there is a better way than this, as it would involve rewriting every single method where I needed to do this?

Why doesn't executing the controller function followed by reloading the page with jquery work, bearing in mind it can still access the `$_SESSION` when doing things in this way?

I have looked at plugins but want to know if there's a native Cake way to do this that I'm overlooking? Ajax isn't mentioned in the Flash Component docs.

Comment: You may want to revise that code a little bit (ideally use your actual code), because as it stands `foo.ctp` would never get rendered, and visiting `/some-controller/foo` would create an endless loop as the method redirects to itself.

Comment: Ugh ok, there's a typo and obviously it should redirect to the page where the user clicked the initial anchor (`/some-controller/index`). I've updated it. In any case it still doesn't work.

Comment: You still have an endless redirect loop there, and `foo.ctp` will not be rendered... I assume that in your original code the redirect is conditional, but without seeing what's actually happening, it's hard to tell what exactly is going wrong. I can shoot in the dark and guess that the template is being rendered, and hence the message is removed from the session, but that's about it.

Comment: There isn't an endless loop. When the user clicks on an anchor (class `.foo-test`) it makes *one* ajax request to `/some-controller/foo`. You're right that it isn't rendered in the browser, because it's an ajax request. But the response data from it (the entire web page) is output in the `console.log(response)`. It then reloads `some-controller/index` (which is rendered in the browser since it's using `window.location.href`). You're right in assuming the logic in `foo()` is conditional based on the outcome of saving to a database. It works fine without ajax, so why not with?

Comment: The question is asked because `SomeController::foo()` is executed. Just because it's done with ajax doesn't mean there is no access to `$_SESSION` - it is still perfectly accessible. It then does a reload of the page (`index.ctp`). In my mind that's the same as doing all of this without ajax - you're executing logic in `SomeController::foo()` which sets the flash messages. On redirect it should render them? I also have `<?= $this->Flash->render() ?>` inside `index.ctp`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've figured this out, with help from @ndm in the comments.

The solution is to remove the PHP redirect in `SomeController::foo()`:

```
public function foo()
{ 
    // There is no template (foo.ctp) associated with this function.
    $this->autoRender = false;

    $this->Flash->set('Records updated', ['element' => 'success']);

    // Remove line below:
    //return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}
```

This is because we're doing an equivalent redirect in jquery:

```
window.location.href = '/some-controller/index';
```

So the ajax request to `/some-controller/foo` still sets the flash messages. Using the jquery redirect reloads `index.ctp` which then has the code to render the flash message.

If you're refactoring code to do things in this way, you need to make sure the action equivalent to `foo()` in this example just sets the flash messages and does not output anything. You can achieve this with `$this->autoRender = false` and then use `$this->Flash->set()` as normal to set your messages.